# Disabling default security using @OAuthSecurity(enabled=false)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

The following [link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_impl_java_adapter_JAXRS.html?lang=en-us) indicates that the security can be disabled using @OAuthSecurity(enabled=false) - see under "Security configuration of a JAX-RS resource"

Question:

- Does it mean that the default security is disabled?

I have a scenario wherein a JavaScript Adapter (developed and being used in a previous version of the product) is auto-deployed on an upgraded server (from 6.1 to 7.0) - using in-place upgrade. This JS adapter had no security tests defined and as such was not protected.

Question:

- When the adapter runs on 7.0 - does the out-of-the-box default security take effect? If so, how does one disable it?

Thanks, in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting MFPF 7.0 there are [two authentication models](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/authentication-concepts/):

- Classic: as you know it from pre-7.0 versions
- OAuth-based

If your adapter is developed in the Classic way, it continues to work as before. If you want a procedure to have no security defined for it, not even the default internal one (when not setting a securityTest), use `securityTest="wl_unprotected"`.

@OAuthSecurity(enabled=false) refers only to Java adapters whereas you are asking about an existing JavaScript adapter... or not?

Comment: I think I got what I was looking for, namely the use of the wl_unprotected setting. I was only using the OAuthSecurity annotation as an example to indicate what I was looking for. Thanks.